# Formula Sequence

Tags: c++, sequence, formula

I need help finding the formula of the sequence for the next problem.

What I think and have for now is `Sn=n(10^n-1)/9` but it just works in some cases...

Here is the description of the problem:

> #### Description
>
> Sn is based upon the sequence positive integers numbers. The value n can be found n times, so the first 25 terms of this sequence are as follows:
>
> ```
> 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7...
> ```
>
> For this problem, you have to write a program that calculates the i-th term in the sequence. That is, determine `Sn(i)`.
>
> #### Input specification
>
> Input may contain several test cases (but no more than 10^5). Each test case is given in a line of its own, and contains an integer i (1 <= i <= 2 * 10^9). Input ends with a test case in which i is 0, and this case must not be processed.
>
> #### Output specification
>
> For each test case in the input, you must print the value of Sn(i) in a single line.
>
> #### Sample input
>
> ```
> 1
> 25
> 100
> 0
> ```
>
> #### Sample output
>
> ```
> 1
> 7
> 14
> ```

Thanks solopilot! I made the code but the online judge show me Time Limit Exceeded, what could be my error?

```
#include <iostream> #include <math.h> using namespace std; int main() {int i;
int NTS;
cin>>i;
while (i>=1){
    NTS=ceil((sqrt(8*i+1)-1)/2);
    cout<<" "<<NTS<<endl;
    cin>>i;
}
return 0;}
```

Comment: Check the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences: https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C2%2C3%2C3%2C3%2C4%2C4%2C4%2C4%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C5%2C6

Comment: "*... but the online judge show me Time Limit Exceeded*" so you might have  answered to slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F(n) = ceiling((sqrt(8*n+1)-1)/2)

---

Say F(n) = a.

Then n ~= a * (a+1) / 2.

Rearranging: a^2 + a - 2n ~= 0.

Solving: a = F(n) = (-1 + sqrt(1+8n)) / 2.
Ignore the negative answer.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern looks like a pyramid. 
Level : 1 3 6 10 15 21 28... 
No    : 1 2 3  4  5  6  7...

```
Level = n(n+1)/2 => elements
3     = 3*4/2    => 6
6     = 6*7/2    => 21
```